# Posting to page feed as PAGE- not as ADMIN

Tags: php, facebook, post, admin, feed

I'm writing an app which posts on a page feed. 
Everything worked fine, it posted as the PAGE, but yesterday it started posting as the ADMIN of the page. Today it's O.K again.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is it a glitch? 
In Case this will happen again I want to be able to handle this.

the php code I'm using:

```
require_once('AppInfo.php');
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$page_access_token = $_POST['page_access_token'];
$page_id           = $_POST['page_id'];
$message           = $_POST['message'];
$link              = $_POST['link'];
$facebook          = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
  'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret()
));

$post_id = $facebook->api(
  '/'.$page_id.'/feed', 
  "post", 
  array(
    'access_token' => $page_access_token, 
    'message'      => $message, 
    'link'         => $link
));
```

Comment: are you using an non-expiry page access token?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes you could check (not prevent, as that is in FB's hands), but I would not recommend trying, its massively over engineering. You may also be responsible for causing the error, see below.

Long answer:
Unfortunately (although it can be good depending which side you stand on) "move fast and break things" (Facebook's Moto) does result in these potential problems. Facebook is generally very quick to pick up any bugs though.

While I can see your concern, there is actually an awful lot you would need to start checking and validating if you were to go down that route, by the end you would have a bloated app which is likely to cause issues in its self. I would say you should be able to sleep easy, knowing that there is a 99.9% chance it won't happen again.

The one and only thing I think *you* could have done to cause this is, on the day it happened to be logged in to Facebook and be using that page as admin. I suggest you try putting this to the test as I would suggest that is quite likely to have happened.